# ConnectikonString For datasource by ODBC Admin

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, datasource

i have Tableu and MongoDB, for connectin Tableu to Mongo i used ODBC Administrator [image: ODBC Administrator]

used ODBC Admin i created Data source(mojoJOJO) :

[image]

[image]

Thanks it i can use my data source and my DB in Tableu
[image]

What the connectionstring used tableu to connect to ma datasource created by ODBC Admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it, ConnectionString to odbc look like this

> Provider=Odbc;DRIVER=DataDirect 8.0
>   MongoDB;HOST=localhost;PORT=27017;DB=product;SD=C:\Users\khodakovskiy\AppData\Local\Progress\DataDirect\MongoDB_Schema\localhost\config.config